# Issues creating daily event

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a daily event in mysql:

```
CREATE EVENT ResetStatus
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    DO

      BEGIN

            IF (DATE('2013-04-05') = CURDATE()) THEN
                UPDATE mytable
                SET resetstatus = 1
                WHERE id = (SELECT pid FROM usertable WHERE priority = 'A');

            END IF;

      END;
```

Get an error:

```
Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

If i take the update statement and place in TOAD and run, it runs with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> If you use the [**mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, [**mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause [**mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

You need to set your client to use a statement delimiter other than `;`, as it currently thinks that the first semicolon that it encounters (at the end of the `UPDATE` statement) is terminating the `CREATE EVENT` statement.

In the MySQL command line client, one can use the `DELIMITER` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;  -- or anything else you like

CREATE EVENT ResetStatus
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY
DO
  BEGIN

        IF (DATE('2013-04-05') = CURDATE()) THEN
            UPDATE mytable
            SET resetstatus = 1
            WHERE id = (SELECT pid FROM usertable WHERE priority = 'A');

        END IF;

  END
;;

DELIMITER ;  -- return to normal
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer